# Ask for recommendation of startpoint of rendering a mesh on web browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, rendering, mesh

I am working on computational fluid dynamics (CFD), where mesh is the first step for any CFD analysis. You can google CFD mesh and get a basic idea of what a CFD mesh looks like.

I am considering how to render this mesh on a web browser which is traditionally only done on a local computer/workstation.

Do you have any recommendations which javascript that I can start with and adding features so to handle this problem? (I am not sure if Google chart API is a good place to start.)
Or is it possible if I have a C++ code already that can generate a mesh file (including its points faces, etc.), when it can be done on back-end, and javascripts can read this mesh file and render it on a web browser?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for 3D rendering with javascript, you can search the web for various engines such [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/).

Note that a high complex mesh can be slow to render or even impossible in some hardwares.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I understand the difficulty in rendering a 3D mesh. And I would only focus on 2D problems.

And I will look into this code, see if it is actionable/programmable for my requirement.